# react-native-fbsdk: Prompting for credentials

Tags: react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

After upgrading `react-native-fbsdk` from 0.5 to 0.6.1, it prompts for FB credentials each time I install my app. This kind of defeats the purpose of having a one-touch Facebook login. Is anyone else noticing a similar behavior and would know how to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Please share the screenshot of prompt you are receiving ?

Comment: Thanks for checking in Akshay. I've updated the post. Previously if I logged into FB once, it would remember my credentials. I'm testing on a simulator and often delete and re-install the app and this behavior is new in 0.6.1.

Comment: It asks for fb creadentials everytime you click on login or everytime you re install the app?

Comment: Each time I re-install the app. Although this is new behavior.

Comment: I have this behavior every time I logout. On Android, it asks for email/password. On iOS it only shows the Continue button.